# Is there anyway to have your iPhone notifications on Windows 10?

Tags: iphone, windows, notifications, pc

Is there a way to get call notifications and alerts on Windows 10 from my iPhone? I spend a lot of time on PC and I always get missed calls. Also my room has no signal so I put my iPhone in the main living area.

Whatsapp gives that ability to connect it to your PC and get notified when someone calls and sends messages to your PC, is there anything similar but for regular calls and messages?

Comment: As far as I'm aware this is a Mac only feature (you can even answer the phone on the Mac)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, Windows is not supported. Both features are part of Continuity (https://support.apple.comHT209456 and https://support.apple.com/HT208386), and Continuity only works on Apple operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

It **was** available in [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/), and Microsoft's "Your Phone" app (before the "Link Mobile" or ["Continue on PC"](https://appadvice.com/app/continue-on-pc/1254607852) apps), but the feature was removed.
[PushSafer](https://www.pushsafer.com/) does it, but it's limited on a free plan.

It seems like it's going to be available again on [Phone Link](https://www.theverge.com/2023/2/28/23618224/microsoft-windows-imessage-support-phone-link-ios-iphone)

Comment: Can you clarify some?  The phrase  “and microsoft your phone (before link mobile or continue on pc)” is confusing at best. Remember this is an Apple centric site, so if you’re referencing Windows technologies, you will want to reference them clearly.

Comment: "your phone" was the application that "link mobile" replaced. "continue on pc" is another application that allows to transfert a microsoft edge tab from the mobile app to the desktop app.

Comment: It’s best to put that info in your answer as an [edit].  Remember, the better you make the answer, the more likely it’s going to be up voted.